# How to position div depending on window size using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I have the following HTML structure:

```css
#jobrow1{
  height:20%;
  font-size:18px;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-left:5%;
  color:white;
}
#jobrow2{
  padding-left:5%;
}
#jobcol1{
  background-color:black;
}
#jobcol2{
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row" id="jobrow1">
  <div class="col-sm-8" id="jobcol1">Description</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="jobcol2">Budget</div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="jobrow2">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    ssssssssssssss 
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
      Fai I'Offeria
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In PC/big screens, the div `#jobcol2` (containing the word "Budget") is displayed above the "Fai I'Offeria" button, but when the screen is smaller than 800px, the description goes in between "Budget" and the button. I want "Budget" to be displayed always on top of the button.

How can I update my code or style `#jobcol2` in order to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome, Please try and keep your questions clear and concise. Limit the code that you show to only the code that is relevant to your problem. It is very inclear what you actually want help with

Comment: i want to show div class jobcol2 above button when window size less then 800px.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution: use `col-xs-*` instead of `col-sm-*`. Right now you are using `col-sm-*` that is applied to screens of 768px and higher. As you don't specify the `col-xs-*` classes, the `div`s will occupy the whole width when the screen is smaller than 768px.

Here is an example of how it would look like:

```css
#jobrow1{
  height:20%;
  font-size:18px;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-left:5%;
  color:white;
}
#jobrow2{
  padding-left:5%;
}
#jobcol1{
  background-color:black;
}
#jobcol2{
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row" id="jobrow1">
  <div class="col-xs-8" id="jobcol1">Description</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4" id="jobcol2">Budget</div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="jobrow2">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    ssssssssssssss 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
      Fai I'Offeria
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Even when the screen is less than 768px, "Budget" will be displayed over the button.

---

If what you want is to have the `div`s occupy 100% when in a small screen, then you should restructure your HTML. Right now you are "thinking in rows" when you should be "thinking in columns". This is your current structure:

```
[ DESCRIPTION-TITLE | BUDGET ]
[ DESCRIPTION       | BUTTON ]
```

If you reorganize the code like this:

```
[ DESCRIPTION-TITLE | DESCRIPTION ]
[ BUDGET            | BUTTON      ]
```

Then you could place the first group with `col-sm-8` and the second with `col-sm-4`, and when the screen is smaller than 768px you will have the description below the description title and the button below the budget title.

Like this:

```css
#jobrow1{
  height:20%;
  font-size:18px;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-left:5%;
  color:white;
  background-color:black;
}    
#jobcol2{
  height:20%;
  font-size:18px;
  padding-top:5px;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8" id="jobcol1">
    <div id="jobrow1">Description</div>
    <div>ssssssssssssss</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="jobcol2">
    <div>Budget</div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Fai I'Offeria</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```